# Change Visual Studio 2010 Web Browser View to Firefox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, firefox, browser

**Visual Studio 2010 has an integrated web browser view**: Menu->View->Other Windows->Web Browser. **How can I change this browser to FireFox?**

**Context**: My goal is to have my favorite browser, as installed on the hard disk, integrated in Visual Studio. Doing so  I could browse my favourite web sites the way I like, while coding. Visual Studio typically fills up my 2 screens, and using this, I could keep my browser in the foreground while not leaving visual studio.

**PLEASE! Note**: This question is not about the WebBrowser control usable in .NET WinForms/WPF projects, nor about testing my own code in a different browser.

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but at a glance, that browser is built-in.  To get similar functionality using other browsers, I suspect you'd need to create your own VS Addin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the "Always on Top" Firefox extension, which helps to keep Firefox in place and visible while fiddling with the code in Visual Studio.

Get [Always On Top](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/always-on-top/).

This helped me so far, even though it is not what I initially looked for.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Here is a Manual solution to Add a new Item named `Web Broweser` in the `Other Windows` menu...

- In the `Tools` Menu, Select `External Tools`...
- Select `Add` in the opened Dialog Box...
- Now Edit According to the the Fields :

```
Title : 'Mozilla Firefox'

Command : [Browse to the file 'firefox.exe' in the Mozilla Firefox Install folder (Default = C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe)]

Arguements : [NULL("")]

Initial Directory : [Path to Mozilla Firefox Install Folder (Default = C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\)]
```

- Click on `Apply` and then on `OK`.
- Note the `Serial No. [Index]` of the Entry `Mozilla Firefox` in the `Tools` Menu.
- Now, In the `Tools` Menu, Select `Customize...`...
- Browse to `Commands` tab.
- Select the `RadioButton` `MenuBar` and in the adjacent `ComboBox`, Select `View | Other Windows`
- Select `WebBrowser` in the `Controls` `ListBox` and Click on `Add Command...`
- In the `Categories` `ListBox` Choose `Tools`.
- Now remember the `Serial No. [Index]` of the Entry `Mozilla Firefox`...
- Find the Entry corresponding to `External Command`  *`Index`*..and Select that Entry.
- Click on `OK`.
- See A new Item `External Command`  *`Index`* has been added...
- Click on `Modify Selection`...
- Change the `Name` property to `Web &Browser` or `Web Browser`
- Click on `Close`.

Check the `View` --> `Other Windows` Menu...You will find Two `MenuItem`s with name `Web Browser`...

The First Item [Without the Icon] is the Newly created Firefox Shortcut...

Comment: PLEASE read the question, and the NOTE! Your answer is nice but EXACTLY NOT what I wanted to ask.

Comment: @Marcel Answer Updated with new Instructions!

Comment: I tried it out and it works as described. However, the new window is not dockable in Visual Studio as all other windows, which is what I am looking for. Please clean up your answer from the old text and i will give it a +1.